renaming files removing both extra dots proceeding the files extension and single dots at the end of the full names
I'm trying to copy a large set of files, with a significant amount failing due to a double dot before the extension or a dot after.
Part of the solution is: Batch rename files that end in a dot.
Another part: Using 'find' to return filenames without extension ..
but I fail to find a combination to do all in once.
I copy an old archive on a Ubuntu Linux from one external NTFS(/exFAT/HPFS) HDD to another external NTFS(/exFAT/HPFS).
Error is a simple "invalid file name"
(there are some folders with the same issue)

What are you using to copy the files? What is exactluy "fail" here? What is the exact error message?

thnx - added that inforto my post above.
